# String is not convertible to an Int in Swift

Tags: string, int

Swift / Xcode

I do not understand why it seems like Swift is not checking the equality for "iPicked_p and numForColorPick" in the IF statement without giving me an error that says "String is not convertible to int"

```
var colors: [String] = ["red", "yellow", "green", "blue", "orange", "purple", "white"]

func pickAColor (iPicked_p: String){
    for num4ColPick in colors{
        if (iPicked_p == colors[num4ColPick]){
            println ("This color is available.")
        } else{ 
            println ("Sorry, this is not an available color"){
    }

}

pickAColor = "red"
```

Comment: In addition to the compiler error, the logic in this code is also wrong, it won’t give the desired output. You want to use the `contains` function instead.

Comment: Hi Konrad and thank you for the input. I will look up that function.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you're looping through your `colors` list which is a list of `String`s, `num4ColPick` will be a `String`, and then you are trying to index a list of `String`s by a `String`, but you can only index a list by a number.

You probably want to change the loop to:

```
for colorToCheck in colors{
    if (iPicked_p == colorToCheck){
        // ...
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew but I am trying to pass a variable to a function that will run through an array that may be changing. My thought was that a value is passed to the function and the function loops through the list to check if there is a match.

Comment: That's fine, it's just that you may have misunderstood how the `for .. in` loop works.

Comment: Maybe just try `for colorToCheck in colors { println(colorToCheck); }` and it might become more clear.

Comment: I've got the for/in part it's the if/else loop using the "iPicked_p" value that's passed to it. The other parts of it don't error. I want to be able to know where it is in the array and be able to access it anytime.

Answer (score 0):

So I believe the following is working for me... I do think that there is a few different ways to do this, but for the sake of closing this out I just want to post a working snippet for those looking for similar answers.

```
var colors: [String] = ["red", "yellow", "green", "blue", "orange", "purple", "white"]

func pickAColor (iPicked_p : String){
    println("Your color is "+"\(iPicked_p)")
    for nameOfColor in colors{
        println("\(nameOfColor)")
        if (iPicked_p == nameOfColor){
            println ("This color is available.")
            println ("\(nameOfColor)")
            let iColor = find (colors, "\(iPicked_p)")! //The ! removes the "some" in result
            println("Your color is at Index +\(iColor)")
        } else{
          // println ("Sorry, this is not a color match.")
        }
    }

}

pickAColor("white") // call the function and pass the color
```

Answer (score 0):

As `num4ColPick` is an index (`Int`) you could enumerate the `indices`

```
for num4ColPick in colors.indices { ...
```

But there is a simpler way, `contains`

```
var colors = ["red", "yellow", "green", "blue", "orange", "purple", "white"]

func pickAColor (iPicked: String){
    if colors.contains(iPicked) {
        print ("This color is available.")
    } else{
        print ("Sorry, this is not an available color")
    }
}

pickAColor(iPicked: "red")
```